# Is there a quick way, in gdb, to break in any method of a class when a certain member variable takes some value?

Tags: c++, gdb

Right now that involves me dropping breakpoints on each member method, and in each adding the same conditional statement regarding one and only member variable. Is there a more succint way to specify, perhaps something like this:

```
b ClassFoo if m_classCounter > bla && m_id == 17
```

?

Comment: you'll probably want a normal watch, what I didn't find written in the answer @Trump211 gave is that you will have to set the watch point on the member variable outside of a member function because otherwise it will be erased as soon as you exit the member function, so for instance if a is an instance of your object and b is a member, you want to watch a.b not b

Comment: So you have to first break somewhere where, say, a pointer to the instance you want exists, and watch ptr->b from there? not set a watch on this->b from within a member func?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is called a watchpoint.  Basically it breaks whenever the value of a given expression changes.

http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html